# Где можно найти компилятор поддерживающий С99?

Tags: c, компилятор, физика, математика

Нужен компилятор С (не с++), IDE необязательно. Компилировать надо чистые си программы (по вычислительной физике и математике) написанные по стандарту С99. Я новичок в программировании и прошу помочь... Где найти этот компилятор? Или как вообще искать его? Любые советы приветствуется...

Comment: gcc поддерживает c99

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте статью на википедии, она предлагает на выбор 3 компилятора. [C99](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)